# Prove that density function of multivariate normal distribution can be represented as multiplication of densities of univariate normal distributions

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Using principal axis theorem prove that density function of multivariate normal distribution can be represented as multiplication of densities of univariate normal distributions.

---

I've been given only very basic definitions of probability theory and I struggle a lot with proving this statement.

I have $$p(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x - a)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
what is density function of univariate normal distribution. 
Next there is $$p(x) = \frac1{(2\pi)^{n/2}|\Sigma|^{1/2}}e^{-\frac12(x - a)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x - a)}, \quad x \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$$
what is density function of multivariate normal distribution. 
I think the main trouble for me is understanding how $\sigma$ transform to $\Sigma$ and I don't know when should I apply principal axis theorem.

Comment: The statement in the title is false.

Comment: The statement is false. In general, a multivariate (joint) density can be expressed as a product of univariate densities (marginals) if and only if the components are independent.

Perhaps you are required to prove that a multivariate normal variable $X$ can be expressed as a matrix product $X=AZ$ where $Z$ is a multivariate normal variable with independent components